# How Can I make drop down search

Tags: cakephp-4.x

In my Index Controller

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null,['type'=>'get'])?>
            
<?= $this->Form->select('categories'[['text'=>'Admin','value'=>'admin','type'=>'submit'],
['text'=>'User','value'=>'user'],['text'=>'Manager','value'=>'Manager']],

['class'=>'form-control',['empty' => true],'value'=>$this->request->getQuery('categories')])?>

 <?= $this->Form->submit(('Search'),['class' => 'btn btn-primary '])?>
       
    <?= $this->Form->end()?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "drop down search"? Please provide more details about the goal, maybe example inputs and outputs, that sort of thing.

Comment: It's like sortation but it has already a value but in dropdown structure and it will only show the selected inputs

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't clarify anything at all for me.

Comment: You can see that in movie sites example for movie genres example I only choose action genre all the movies with action genre will appear

Comment: You want to submit your form, and return a page with matching results? Or you want a change in the drop-down to trigger an Ajax query that returns results? Or you already have a list of results in the browser and just want to change which are visible?

Comment: I want return a page with matching result of list in the same page

Comment: public function index()
    {
$categories = $this->request->getQuery('categories');
if($categories){
                $query = $this->Users->find('all')->contain(['Profiles','Skills'])->
                where(['Or'=>['role like'=>'%'.$categories.'%']]);*/

        }else{
            $query = $this->Users;
        }
  $users = $this->paginate($query,['limit'=>'10',
            'sortableFields' => ['Profiles.name'],
            'contain'=>['Profiles','Skills']]);
        //

        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }

Comment: I tried this method but the problem is each time you select a input you need to press submit

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an Ajax solution. Do you know about that and just struggling with how to get some part of it to work, or are you not aware of Ajax at all?

Comment: No I am not aware

Comment: I would use Datatables to achieve this.  https://github.com/ypnos-web/cakephp-datatables is a good plugin (be sure to find the cakephp 4 branch if you are using 4 - check the closed issues.)  You will have to play around to make your own Multiselect dropdown work.